# Coremltools problems converting Tensorflow model to Core ML with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I'm training a small model and then trying to export it to core ml using

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
```

But I'm getting an error:

> AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'topology'

After a bit of googling, someone suggested that topology is deprecated or something, and suggested replacing `topology` with `saving`. I probably did this wrong, but I opened up

`~/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py`

and in the `_KERAS_LAYER_REGISTRY` I tried changing

`_keras.engine.topology.InputLayer:_layers2.default_skip,`

to

`_keras.engine.saving.InputLayer:_layers2.default_skip,`

and that gave me a slightly different error:

> AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.saving' has no attribute 'InputLayer'

I feel like a fish out of water here, as I haven't ever worked with Tensorflow, or core ML before. So be gentle with me. Here's some code:

```
batch_size = 20
epochs = 10
test_size = 500
input_dim = 30

# Model Architecture
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(input_dim, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())

# Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(input_dim, activation='relu'))

# Logits Layer
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

rmsprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop,
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

accuracy = model.evaluate(x=x_test, y=y_test, batch_size=batch_size)

print("Overall accuracy: {}".format(accuracy[1]))

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

Comment: Which version of Keras do you use?  
It seems the latest release of coremltools supports Keras 2.1.3. Try downgrading to 2.1.3 to see if it works in this way.
In the latest release of Keras (2.2.0), keras.engine was quite refactored and I wouldn't be suprised this causes the problem.

Comment: I can confirm I got the same errors with Keras 2.2.0 but with 2.1.6 it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, I tried downgrading and that seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: Same error and coreml suggested to downgrade from Keras 2.2.2 to Keras 2.1.3